# Connecting to an UK only restricted API from a server overseas

Tags: proxy, api

I'm running/writing a little app that connects to an API that only allows UK traffic to access it. I'd like to run it on my web server which is hosted in the US. Is there some way I can make the API respond as of my server is in the UK?

Comment: One option would be, rent a cheap VPS or even shared hosting in the UK, and route the call through that! I'm sure there are better ideas but, it's still an option :)

Comment: @dave I'm not sure there are better ideas than that...

Comment: @Dave I **am** sure there are **no** better ideas.

Comment: That's cleared that up then.  This makes me a bit sad, I like my US hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an option would be to rent a cheap VPS or maybe even shared hosting in the UK, and simply route the call through that!